# Add a custom date time format specifier for default format provider

Tags: c#, datetime, format, datetime-format

I need to define a custom format specifier without using `IFormatProvider`.

```
var str = DateTime.Now.ToString("myCustomSpecifier");
```

Why not using format provider? because I'm working in a code generation environment and specifying second parameter for `ToString` wouldn't be possible.

At the same time we wan't to keep the method `.ToString()` so creating another method using extension method is not acceptable.

I tried searching through `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` members to see if there is any configurable thing I can set for this. Or if I can set the default format provider. I couldn't find anything.

Does anybody think it's possible? if so how?

Comment: Would extention methods be kosher?

Comment: if you mean defining `.ToCustomString` and use it instead; No it's not acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this directly on the culture of the current thread

```
var cultureInfo = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR").Clone();
cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd.MM.yyyy";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```

Put this code in the constructor of the App.xaml.cs.

The `ToString("d")` method will show your custom partern.

Answer (score 0):

```
internal const string DATETIME_FORMAT = "dd MMM yyyy";

public void Method()
{
    var str = DateTime.Now.ToString(DATETIME_FORMAT);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation.  Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers.  Your answer is in the moderation queue for being low-quality.